# Android Recyclerview update calendar on scroll

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview with a calendar above. How is it possible to update the current date in the calendar if I scroll the recyclerview through the events of the day.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `RecyclerVew`  provide an addOnScrollListener method

private OnScrollLoadMore mOnScrollLoadMore;//initalize  in your activity class
 recycler_view.addOnScrollListener(mOnScrollLoadMore);// add onScrollListener to recyclerview

public class OnScrollLoadMore extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

```
private IOnScrollListener mOnScrollListener;
private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private Activity mContext;
private boolean mLoading = true;

public interface IOnScrollListener {
    void onScrollComplete();
}

public OnScrollLoadMore(Activity activity, LinearLayoutManager layoutManager) {
    this.mContext = activity;
    this.mLayoutManager = layoutManager;
}

public void setOnScrollListener(IOnScrollListener onScrollListener) {
    this.mOnScrollListener = onScrollListener;
}

public void setLoading(boolean loading) {
    this.mLoading = loading;
}

@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
    Utils.hide_keyboard(mContext);
}

@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                 setLoading(false);
                mOnScrollListener.onScrollComplete();
}
```

}

//In Activity you want the event to triggered
    override
    public void onScrollComplete() {
       // do your work
    }

Perform your task of updating current date

Comment: I want to achieve that the date in the recycler view, there the user is is displayed in the calendar above. I think I don't understand you, where I get the Id of the item with the date? I hope you understand what I want

Comment: @johannes you earlier mentioned that you want to update the date of calender above recyclerview, on scroll of recyclerview but here you are mentioning something else please mention clearly so that i can help appropriately 